# Qt Regexp extract <p> tags from Html string

Tags: html, regex, qt, extract, qregexp

I have a RichText and I store its Html source from the QTextEdit in a string.
What I'd like to do is extract all the lines one-by-one (I have 4-6 lines).
The string looks like this:

```
//html opening stuff
<p style = attributes...><span style = attributes...>My Text</span></p>
//more lines like this
//html closing stuff
```

So I need the WHOLE LINES from the opening p tag to the closing p tag (including the p tags too).
I checked and tried everything I found around here and on other sites, but still no result.

Here's my code ("htmlStyle" is the input string):

```
QStringList list;
QRegExp rx("(<p[^>]*>.*?</p>)");
int pos = 0;

while ((pos = rx.indexIn(htmlStyle, pos)) != -1) {
    list << rx.cap(1);
    pos += rx.matchedLength();
}
```

Or is there any other way to do this without regex?

Comment: This question is a classic X-Y problem and is incomplete until you tell us exactly why you need to iterate paragraphs in your richtext document. What will you do with these paragraphs? Note that "I'll parse them further" is not the way to go: you really don't want to write your own HTML parser. There's nothing you can do with a text string that has some HTML in it unless you parse it. Leave parsing to Qt, it already does it anyway. Leverage the HTML parser that Qt gives you access to.

Comment: You could try xml reader with QDomDocument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below is pure java way, hope this helps:

```
int startIndex = htmlStyle.indexOf("<p>");
        int endIndex = htmlStyle.indexOf("</p>");
        while (startIndex >= 0) {
            endIndex = endIndex + 4;// to include </p> in the substring
            System.out.println(htmlStyle.substring(startIndex, endIndex));
            startIndex = htmlStyle.indexOf("<p>", startIndex + 1);
            endIndex = htmlStyle.indexOf("</p>", endIndex + 1);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it will work somehow! I just need to think about it. There is no substring in Qt. I try to use "section()", it returns 4 empty strings, which is partially good, because there are 4 matches in my current string. I just need to work out how to get the actual text.

Comment: Now it works like a charm! Thanks again!
`QStringRef subString(&htmlStyle, startIndex, endIndex-startIndex);`
It goes in htmlStyle from startIndex and stops after the length of endIndex-startIndex!

Answer (score 2):

HTML/XML is not a regular grammar. You cannot parse it with a regex. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/701166/1329652). Parsing HTML is not trivial.

You can iterate the paragraphs in a rich text document using `QTextDocument`, `QTextBlock`, `QTextCursor`, etc. All the HTML parsing is taken care of for you. This is exactly the subset of HTML that is supported by `QTextEdit`: it uses `QTextDocument` as an internal representation. You can get it directly from the widget using `QTextEdit::document()`. E.g:

```
void iterate(QTextEdit * edit) {
   auto const & doc = *edit->document();
   for (auto block = doc.begin(); block != doc.end(); block.next()) {
      // do something with text block e.g. iterate its fragments
      for (auto fragment = block.begin(); fragment != block.end(); fragment++) {
         // do something with text fragment
      }
   }
}
```

Instead of incorrectly parsing HTML by hand you should explore the structure of the `QTextDocument` and use it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

For those who need the full Qt solution, I figured it out based on @Aditya Poorna 's answer. Thanks for that tip!

Here's the code:

```
int startIndex = htmlStyle.indexOf("<p");
int endIndex = htmlStyle.indexOf("</p>");

while (startIndex >= 0) {
    endIndex = endIndex + 4;
    QStringRef subString(&htmlStyle, startIndex, endIndex-startIndex);
    qDebug() << subString;
    startIndex = htmlStyle.indexOf("<p", startIndex + 1);
    endIndex = htmlStyle.indexOf("</p>", endIndex + 1);
}
```

"QStringRef subString" goes in "htmlStyle" from "startIndex" until the length of "endIndex-startIndex"!